# How to get the previous data or the latest data by id in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I created a billing system where I have a fields of `meter_no`, `prev_reading`, `current_reading` and `consumed`.
In my onchange method, when I select a meter number, my `prev_reading` will be automatically filled with the value of the last saved `current_reading` by id of a `meter_no`. Here's my onchange method:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('meter_no')
def onchange_meter_no(self):
    ids = self.search([('meter_no','=',self.meter_no.id)])
    last_id = ids and max(ids)
    if self.meter_no:
        self.prev_reading = last_id.current_reading or None
```

But this always returns the second value, not the last data. Example, BILL-01 `prev_reading = 0.0`, `current_reading = 10.0`, and `consumed = 10.0`. In BILL-02, the data is correct as expected where, `prev_reading = 10.0`, then I entered `current_reading = 20`, then `consumed = 10`. Here in third billing, BILL-03 `prev_reading` is always `10`, it's always the same until fourth and so on. What's wrong with this? I already used the `max()` to get the last id.

Comment: the variable **ids** isn't list of IDs (the return value of search method is recordset). Even you give max function, the max function will not take the max ID. I think like that.

Comment: Thank you @afwanwh . So, what is your possible solutions here?

Comment: Can't we use `max()` in a recordset?

Comment: You got the answer from other user. It's solved.

Answer (score 11):

You could pass options to search function to get the last id like this:

```
record_ids = self.search([('meter_no','=',self.meter_no.id)], order='id desc', limit=1)
last_id = record_ids.id
```

...

Comment: Thank you very much @thangtn, it works. I can't mark it as answer because I only have less than 15 reputations.